# Is spaying or neutering of stray animals for population control ok?

Tags: five-precepts, animals

Killing of stray animals like dogs and cats violates the first precept.

However, is spaying or neutering of stray animals for population control acceptable from Buddhism's perspective? Does it violate any precept or teaching?

Comment: Sorry, if this is not relevant but is spaying a stray beneficial to it or the species? Or is it solely for the benefit of the human beings living in the same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found MN8 to be useful for answer questions such as this. It has many everyday rules to consider, starting with:

> [MN8:12.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn8/en/sujato#mn8:12.2): ‘Others will be cruel, but here we will not be cruel.’

The lives of stray animals are short and harsh. We welcome animals into our home and neuter them for their benefit and ours. And that last consideration is summarized here:

> [AN4.95:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/an4.95/en/sujato#an4.95:3.3): But the person who practices to benefit both themselves and others is the foremost, best, chief, highest, and finest of the four.

Look at these suttas, let us know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

In my city , the dogs started becoming angry. They bit people.Even I was bitten once. I forgave the dogs and I did not wish to neuter them. Neither did I became afraid of them. I understood that it was a result of karma. However authorities took the menace of dog biting kids , adults , women etc very seriously. They captured most of the stray dogs in my colony and probably neutered them or killed them.

As a believer in Buddha , I do not intend any harm to any individual, in any way. It is not a matter of precepts. It is about love and compassion for every being. Whether it is the Lion or the deer(which is a food for lion) , I wish them all the best and I remain equanimous.

I took my example because in texts you will not find anything about stray cats or dogs. Hope this answers your question.